# How to remove strings from lines that begin with a specific character?

Tags: bash

I want to write a bash script to simultaneously:

1. Take the "chromosome" and adjacent digit (here, it's "1") for every line that begin with ">" and abbreviate it to "chr{digit}" (e.g., chr1)
2. Move "chr{digit}" to the front and remove everything else
3. Remove all the "N"s from the second row onwards

My attempt:

I first try to find every line that begins with ">" and then find the digit after the string "chromosome ". This digit is appended to the substring ">chr" and everything else in the line is removed.

```
grep '^\>' | grep -oP "chromosome \s+\K\w+" | cat "chr" GCF_000001405.40_GRCh38.p14_genomic.fna
```

Next, I remove all the "Ns" in the lines that do not begin with ">"

```
awk '/^>/ {printf("%s%s\t",(N>0?"\n":""),$0);N++;next;} {printf("%s",$0);} END {printf("\n");}' < GCF_000001405.40_GRCh38.p14_genomic.fna | sed 's/N//g' | tr "\t" "\n" > genome.fna
```

My code has been hanging for ~1 hour and not executing.

Input:

```
>NC_000001.11 Homo sapiens chromosome 1, GRCh38.p14 Primary Assembly
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN

gaaagtGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTA
>NC_000001.12 Homo sapiens chromosome 2, GRCh38.p14 Primary Assembly
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
gaaagtGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTAGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTA
```

Desired output:

```
>chr1 
gaaagtGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTA

>chr2
gaaagtGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTAGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTA
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `GNU awk` or (some) `nawk` but not `mawk`:

```
$ awk '
    /^>/{
        match($0, / chromosome ([0-9]+)/, a)
        print ">chr"a[1]
    }
    /^[gactGACT]+/{print $0"\n"}
' file
```

or

```
awk '
    /^>/{
        x=gensub(/.* chromosome ([0-9]+).*/, "\\1", "g", $0)
        print ">chr"x}
    /^[gactGACT]+/{print $0"\n"}
' file
```

##### Output

```
>chr1
gaaagtGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTA

>chr2
gaaagtGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTAGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTA
```

Comment: Quenot :  no idea what you're talking about ::::::::::::::: :::::::::: :::::::::::::: :::::::::: :::::: :::::::::: :::::: :::::::::: ::::::::: :::::::::::::: `nawk '{ print gensub(/ /, "=", "g", $0) }'
nawk: calling undefined function gensub`   ::::::::::::::: `nawk` neither has `gensub()` nor ability to create 3rd argument array from `match()` (granted my `nawk` is only the `macOS` built-in one version `20200816` so maybe it's a new feature)

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like a case for more basic string handling with `sed`.

```
$: sed -E '/^N*$/d; s/^([GgAaTtCc]+)$/\1\n/; s/^>.*chromosome[[:space:]]+([0-9]).*/>chr\1/; ' file
>chr1
gaaagtGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTA

>chr2
gaaagtGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTAGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTA
```

Even if you don't have GNU `sed`, I think this version should work the same -

```
$: sed '/^N*$/d
 s/^\([GgAaTtCc][GgAaTtCc]*\)$/\1\n/
 s/^>.*chromosome[[:space:]][[:space:]]*\([0-9]\).*/>chr\1/ ' file
>chr1
gaaagtGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTA

>chr2
gaaagtGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTAGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTA
```

This logic checks & deletes `^N*$` lines first since they are most common from the example given. It adds a blank line after data lines since you had one in your example output, and does a pretty simple scan/replace on keyword lines. Should be pretty efficient.

As an aside - this:

```
grep '^\>' | grep -oP "chromosome \s+\K\w+" | cat "chr" GCF_000001405.40_GRCh38.p14_genomic.fna
```

is an antipattern.

Try not to `grep` to a `grep` to a `cat`, *especially* if you already plan to use an `awk` later. Try to consolidate patterns when you can, and executions so that you don't have multiple copies of a executable running when you don't need to, *especially* if it involves any loops (which I don't think you did here.) Note that my solution is one `sed`, and [Giles' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75948088/8656552) is one call to `awk`, each of which handles all the patterns in one pass.

More importantly, `...  | cat "chr" ...` isn't going to work as you intended here. I'm not sure what you meant it to do, but that call to `cat` is going to try and read two files named `chr` and `GCF_000001405.40_GRCh38.p14_genomic.fna` and send them to `stdout`, but is going to completely ignore the input from the `grep` pipe.

If you need `cat` to read from both local files AND a pipe, use `-` to list the pipe on the argument list.

```
$: echo a>a; echo b>b
$: grep . a | cat b
b
$: grep . a | cat b -
b
a
$: grep . a | cat - b
a
b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo \
   '>NC_000001.11 Homo sapiens chromosome 1, GRCh38.p14 Primary Assembly
    NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
    NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
    
    gaaagtGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTA
    >NC_000001.12 Homo sapiens chromosome 2, GRCh38.p14 Primary Assembly 
    NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
    gaaagtGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTAGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTA' |
```

> ```
> awk '(NF*=!/^N+$/)==!_ || NF-=!!NF' FS=',.*$|^.+chromosome ' OFS='>chr'
> ```

```
>chr1
gaaagtGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTA
>chr2
gaaagtGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTAGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTA
```

change `OFS` to `OFS='\n>chr'` and get it with blank line in between but one extra leading edge blank line

```
 1  
 2  >chr1
 3  gaaagtGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTA
 4  
 5  >chr2
 6  gaaagtGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTAGAGGTTGCCTGCCCTGTCTCCTA
```

Comment: This is brainfuck code? ^^ Just a joke, no worries =) If I'm sysadmin junior and I have to adapt this, will be a PITA! But approach interesting :) Are you a Math guy?